# Get current Property Group Id at Shopware 6 administration twig component

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

In Shopware 6 `sw-property-option-detail.html.twig` administration component override I'm able to condition by `currentOption`, is it possible to condition by current Property Group ID?

```
<div v-if="currentOption.id === '24cbe94e41744b7999bd873f1a06a498' || currentOption.id === 'c0d02d1738fd4293a489695787e06b5c' || currentOption.id === '3ddd3f308917476b8676da652048e824'">
    <!--
        do
    -->
</div>
```

Also if someone can give a tip, if I can find these variables via `console.log(Shopware);` in the future this will help me a lot. As I'm comfortable with frontend `{{ dump }}`, but not with Administration yet.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `twig`? `v-if` is not part of `twig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to move such logic to your component code, if possible, so the `.twig` will mostly contain clean markup.

You should, however, be able to use something like an `v-if="thisProperty == thatProperty"`. E.g:

```
<div v-if="thisProperty == thatProperty">
  show this stuff
</div>
```

That, however, will as far as I remember mean an empty div shows up even when the statement is false. To avoid that, use `<template>` instead. I have something similar in my own plugin components and it works for me.

As for testing variable content; you can output the contents of variables from the component code using `console.log()`, and from within `.twig` you can do. E.g:

```
<div class="myDiv">
{{ currentOption }}
</div>
```

It will be "dumped" as an inconvenient text string and can result in very long lines. You may make it more convenient by dumping into a `<textarea>`.

Alternatively, `{{ console.log(currentOption) }}` should also work to tell you if the property of interest exists.

**In the component `.js` code**, you may be able to `console.log` from the `created` or `updated` lifecycles (untested). E.g:

```
data() {
  return {
    updateCount: 0
  };
},
updated: function () {
  if ("undefined" !== typeof this.currentOption && this.updateCount == 0) {
    ++this.updateCount;
    console.log(this.currentOption);  
  }
},
```

But, that may trigger multiple `console.log`s without the `if`, so be careful. Not sure if there is a better "vue way" to access something on first page load, but this works in one of my own plugins.

**Finally**, I am just stating this for other Shopware newcomers, because it is very confusing and poorly documented; `dump()` is normally exclusive to the storefront `.twig` files, which are rendered on the server-side, and even then it still needs to be enabled via `.env` debugging parametres before you can use it. It will normally not work in production mode, and sometimes it is better to create your own twig extension to have the dump saved as a file. E.g. Using `file_put_contents`, because some objects are so large they might crash your server and/or browser. To enable debug mode in your `.env` file:

```
APP_DEBUG=1
APP_ENV="dev"
```

For the `vue.js` based administration, which is client-side, you will want to use `console.log()`. But you probably want to use it from within the component code rather than from the `.twig` files, because then you can better control the output. It is very important you remember to remove the `console.log` code again, because it can slow down the back-end for your users and cause huge memory usage if the objects are large and/or the dump is triggered repeatedly (as is sometimes the case in vue components, depending on where and how you dump/log things).